# How to make route direction between multiple markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to make route direction between Manly Beach -> Bondi Beach -> Coogee Beach -> Maroubra Beach -> Cronulla Beach and finally go from Cronulla Beach to Manly Beach

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VaQwqK

Answer (score 25, accepted):

related questions:

- [Google map waypoints from geoJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272247/google-map-waypoints-from-geojson)
- [Google Maps Api - drawing routes from an array of points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28928906/google-maps-api-drawing-routes-from-an-array-of-points)

1. put the locations array in the order you want to get the directions in.

```
var locations = [
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3]
  ];
```

2. create the request for the [DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) with the first marker in `origin` the last marker in `destination`, push the rest into the waypoints array:

```
if (i == 0) request.origin = marker.getPosition();
else if (i == locations.length - 1) request.destination = marker.getPosition();
else {
  if (!request.waypoints) request.waypoints = [];
  request.waypoints.push({
    location: marker.getPosition(),
    stopover: true
  });
}
```

3. call the directions service.

```
directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
  }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5om01gq3/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var locations = [
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3]
];

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();


  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;
  var request = {
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));

    if (i == 0) request.origin = marker.getPosition();
    else if (i == locations.length - 1) request.destination = marker.getPosition();
    else {
      if (!request.waypoints) request.waypoints = [];
      request.waypoints.push({
        location: marker.getPosition(),
        stopover: true
      });
    }

  }
  directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```