# How to change multiple icon marker from direction in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

Sory for my english, i want to create route direction with multiple marker in google maps, i try from this tutorial [Direction with multipe marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523773/how-to-make-route-direction-between-multiple-markers)

now i want to change the icon marker, the default marker is A,B,C,D like this screen shoot [image]

[image]

my question is how to change the default icon with my icon...try to use `directionsDisplay.setOptions( { suppressMarkers: true } );`the icon si not appers....this my code:

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var locations = [
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3]
];

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();


  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsDisplay.setOptions( { suppressMarkers: true } );
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;
  var request = {
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      icon:'images/dalamkota.png'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));

    if (i == 0) request.origin = marker.getPosition();
    else if (i == locations.length - 1) request.destination = marker.getPosition();
    else {
      if (!request.waypoints) request.waypoints = [];
      request.waypoints.push({
        location: marker.getPosition(),
        stopover: true
      });
    }

  }
  directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

Any wrong with my code....???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `map: map` part when creating markers:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      icon:'http://s7.postimg.org/wg6bu3jpj/pointer.png',
      map: map
    });
```

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/2017/

Comment: Ok this work and how to keep default start and end marker icon ...the default is A and B...