# How to get car route on Google maps if I have 3 or more coordinates? Rails 5 gmaps API

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I need to make a car route on Gmaps. I know how it works with 2 points  [(a link)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple) but can I do same with 3 or more points?
I will be grateful for any tips or useful links.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate. Did you mean something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523773/how-to-make-route-direction-between-multiple-markers

Comment: Oh yes exactly what I need thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

See this link.You set selected some waypoints. 
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/directions-waypoints